# Expandable sections powered with Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using the following example by Apple https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html to create expandable sections at the moment i have all my data in sqlite (core data) because of the icloud thing (sync across devices).My main problem is that any time i want to delete a section from the UITableView i have to call

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

the correct way is to delete the entities from the sqlite any help on this topic?

Comment: Looks like you need to delete the object from Core Data. If you don't know enough about Core Data to do that, I suggest Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, I can help you do this with [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) if you're OK with using an `NSFetchedResultsController` alternative. There is a `TLCollapsibleTableViewController` class that can be integrated with Core Data or you can roll your own collapsible controller without too much trouble.